# Reading file into a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 52*5 array and a file with 52 lines (5 integers in each row). I have to fill my array with these numbers. Is this a proper sollution?

```
std::ifstream infile("lottosz.dat"); 
std::string temp;
int line = 0;

while (std::getline(infile, temp))
{
    std::istringstream is(temp);
    is >> lottosz[line][0] >> lottosz[line][1] >> lottosz[line][2] 
       >> lottosz[line][3] >> lottosz[line][4];
    line++;
}
```

Comment: Seems more like a code review question.

Comment: It is *a* solution, and most certainly would work fine. You might want to check `line` though, so it doesn't become to big.

Comment: You may also want to test the `is` extraction line as well. If someone snuck in less than 5 integers...

Comment: Checkin gthe `is` would also indicate problems such as someone typed in "abc" instead of a number...